# customize letter sizes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text field with a max length of 4 characters. I also have a layer which will allow me to show what i type in the text field into my image. However; i need to customize the sizes of the letters been typed. if someone types 4 letters the first letter should be big and the next one small. I have 4 different items where i want to include this. i was thinking of using switch statements.

```
   myProjectpage.view.applySomeTextLineText = function() {
        myProjectpage.model.logTime( "applySomeTextLineText", "start" );
        var layout = myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.Layout;
        for ( var i = 0; i < layout.layers.length; i++ ) {
            layer = layout.layers[i];
            if ( layer.property ==  myProjectpage.TEXT_LINE_1 ) {
                var layerHTML = "";
                if (  myProjectpage.model.labelType == "myaddedtext" && $("#dropdownchoice1").val() == "only1textfield" ) {
                    switch( myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text.length ) {
                    case 1:
                        //letters with diferent sizes.
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        layerHTML = "a" + "span style='font-size: 1.1em;>b</span>" + "c";

                        break; 
                     case 4: 
break;
                    }
                } else {
                    layerHTML = myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text;

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `layer` is an HTML element and you want to apply styles directly to the element, you should be able to modify the text size with jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function and either a `switch` or a set of `if` statements. If `layer` isn't an HTML element, you'll need to replace `$(layer)` with the appropriate selector.

Of course, you can always set up styles for the four text sizes and toggle them in your `switch` or `if` statement.

Here's a quick proof of concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  var layer = $('#sized_text_output');

  $('#sized_text_input').on('input', function() {
    var sized_text = $(this).val();
    $('#sized_text_output').text(sized_text);

    switch (sized_text.length) {
      case 1:
        $(layer).css({ 'font-size': '4.5em' });
        break;
      case 2:
        $(layer).css({ 'font-size': '3em' });
        break;
      case 3:
        $(layer).css({ 'font-size': '1.5em' });
        break;
      case 4:
        $(layer).css({ 'font-size': '1em' });
        break;
    }

    // if (sized_text.length === 1) {
    //   $(layer).css({'font-size': '4.5em'});
    // } else if (sized_text.length === 2) {
    //  $(layer).css({'font-size': '3em'});
    // } else if (sized_text.length === 3) {
    //  $(layer).css({'font-size': '1.5em'});
    // } else if (sized_text.length === 4) {
    //  $(layer).css({'font-size': '1em'});
    // }

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sized_text_input" maxlength="4">
<div id="sized_text_output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Code is fine I made a variable called usersText to make it a little short and not to write " myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text; " all the time. It is a little hard to remember where exactly the "" go. Look at your "" and the ones i did for case 1 and 2 you will see the difference. The CharAt() method will grab the characters in the string or text the user types in.

```
enter code here

myProjectpage.view.applySomeTextLineText = function() {
        myProjectpage.model.logTime( "applySomeTextLineText", "start" );
        var layout = myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.Layout;
        for ( var i = 0; i < layout.layers.length; i++ ) {
            layer = layout.layers[i];
            if ( layer.property ==  myProjectpage.TEXT_LINE_1 ) {
                var layerHTML = "";
                if (  myProjectpage.model.labelType == "myaddedtext" && $("#dropdownchoice1").val() == "only1textfield" ) {
                    var usersText =
```

myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text;
switch( myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text.length ) {
                        case 1:

```
 layerHTML = "<span style='font-size:2.9em;'>" + usersText.charAt(0) + "</span>";


              //letters with diferent sizes.
                        break;
                    case 2:
layerHTML = "<span style='font-size:2.5em;'>" + usersText.charAt(0) + "</span>" + "<span style='font-size:2.5em;'>" + usersText.charAt(1) + "</span>"; 
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        layerHTML = "a" + "span style='font-size: 1.1em;>b</span>" + "c";

                        break; 
                     case 4: 
break;
                    }
                } else {
                    layerHTML = myProjectpage.model.currentChoices.TextLine1Text;

                }
```